# Ref to firebase storage not working with variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to store profile pictures from users in my Firebase Storage. Because every user can only have 1 profile picture in my project, I encoded the email using `window.btoa(emailInput)` and that has to be the file name of the uploaded profile picture.

I tried to use this code to make it work, but it gives an error because, I think, you can't have a variable in the `.child()` element.

```js
/* Upload the profile picture to Firebase Storage and get the URL */
let fileButton = document.getElementById("signupProfilePicFile"); /* "Choose a file" button */
let uploader = document.getElementById("uploadProgressBar"); /* Progress bar */
fileButton.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    // Get the file
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    let emailInput = document.getElementById("signupEmail").value;
    let encodedEmail = window.btoa(emailInput);
    
    // Create a storage ref
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("profile-pictures/");
    var profilePicRef = storageRef.child(encodedEmail) /* !!!HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!! */
    
    // Upload the file
    var task = profilePicRef.put(file);

    // Update progress bar
    task.on("state_changed",
        function progress(snapshot) {
            var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            uploader.value = percentage;
        },
        function error(err) {

        },
        function complete() {

        }
    );
})
```

```html
<p>Email:</p>
<input type="text" name="email" id="signupEmail">
<br>
<p>Profile picture file input:</p>
<input type="file" name="file" id="signupProfilePicFile">
<progress value="0" max="100" id="uploadProgressBar">0%</progress>
```

When I remove the variable "encodedEmail" and replace it with a string (eg "profile-pic") it does work.

Can someone help me fix my issue or can't you really not enter a variable in a `.child()`?

Comment: Which exact error are you getting? Your code should work correctly. Since you don't have anything in `function error(err) {}` you cannot see the potential errors. Do you have some security rules which prevent writing to the bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom metadata:

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`profile-pictures/${encodedEmail}`);

var metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg',
  customMetadata: {
    'yourEncodedEmail': encodedEmail
  }
};

var task = storageRef.put(file, metadata);
```

Comment: Does that mean it will only allow files with a .jpg or .jpeg extension?

Comment: You can save it without any extensions but I think you need to declare content type as an image/jpeg